# Flow: Scheduled Path Flow Only Updates When Time-based Field is Updated

Tags: visual-workflow, scheduled

I have created a Record-triggered Flow, set to be triggered whenever a record is updated or created and to run "every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements".

I have added a Scheduled Path based on a StartDate field, plus 3 DAYS. It sends a reminder email.

The problem is that a new entry only appears in the Time-based Workflow queue not on any record update, but only when there is a new record created or an update to the StartDate.

Due to the settings, I would expect any update to run the flow and add an item to the Time-based workflow queue. And I need this to happen because I need to update a different field to cause existing records to have this email reminder added to the queue.

What am I misunderstanding here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entries in the `Setup | Time-Based Workflow` using *every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements*

**Appear**

- When the record matches the Flow's entry criteria. And only the first time unless DML causes the record to no longer qualify for entry (see Disappear) at which point the next time DML occurs to satisfy the entry criteria, a new TBW is created from the scheduled path.

**Disappear**

- When the record no longer matches the Flow's entry criteria or
- When the time trigger transpires and the scheduled path executes

**Adjust**

- When the reference date(time) of the scheduled path changes value on any DML operation.

Once the record has already generated the TBW events, changing any other field value on that record will not cause the flow to even execute, let alone any new TBWs to appear.

To solve your issue, some options:

- Use *created and every time it is edited* (which can lead to many, unintended TBWs)
- Have a separate Flow to handle the additional field, perhaps using subflows to handle shared logic

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I added a simple checkmark field to the condition and updated that, and all were created.

Comment: @cropedy In the "Disappear" list I would add "When the reference date(time) of the scheduled path is updated to NULL or is updated to a date which makes it automatically transpire".